# Print python list without quotation marks or space after commas

Tags: python, list

So right now I have a list of file names. I want to print them without the space after the comma and without quotation marks.

So basically I have a file that has the following output:

```
['1', '2', '3']
```

And I want the output to be

```
1,2,3
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `join` method.

```
>>> your_list = ['1', '2', '3']
>>> print(', '.join(your_list))
1, 2, 3
```