# how to remove quotes from a list of dataframes in python

Tags: python, list

I have a python list of strings that are the names of variables representing dataframes.

```
my_dataframe_list = ['df1', 'df2', 'df3']
```

so conceptually, the single quotes need to be removed and the final output should be a list of dataframes.

```
my_dataframe_list = [df1, df2, df3]
```

Comment: `import ast` then `ast.literal_eval(List)` ?

Comment: They don't seem to want to parse a string list. I think that's a misinterpretation.

Comment: @Carcigenicate okay. Should I reopen? Looks unclear still

Comment: @anky I don't think your dupe is what they're asking, but ya, it's not clear. They don't have quotes around the initial list, so it doesn't seem like the starting data is a string. It seems like they're confused about what the quotes in the printed representation mean.

Comment: I think you want [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44639357/print-python-list-without-quotation-marks-or-space-after-commas) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445970/how-to-properly-print-a-list), then wrap it in `[`/`]`s.

Comment: are `a` `b` and `c` defined variables?

Comment: I edited my question. the initial list has quotes for all the items in it which i need to eliminate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [access it from `globals() or locals()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9437799/13138364):

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([2, 4, 6])
my_dataframe_list = ['df1', 'df2']

my_dataframe_list = [globals()[df] for df in my_dataframe_list]
```

```py
my_dataframe_list[0]

#    0
# 0  1
# 1  2
# 2  3
```

```py
my_dataframe_list[1]

#    0
# 0  2
# 1  4
# 2  6
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the built-in [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) method:

```
my_dataframe_list = ['df1', 'df2', 'df3']
my_dataframe_list = [eval(df) for df in my_dataframe_list]
```

Instead of the list comprehension, you can use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
my_dataframe_list = ['df1', 'df2', 'df3']
my_dataframe_list = list(map(eval, my_dataframe_list))
```

**But beware, the `eval` method is dangerous**; you should never use it on untrusted input. See this article for more details: [Eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Perhaps a more filtered list would be better:

```
my_dataframe_list = [eval(df) for df in my_dataframe_list if df.startswith('df') and df[2:].isdigit()]
```

But of course, the best thing you can do is to structure your existing code in a way that doesn't require the use of `eval`.

---

This Stack Overflow post suggests the [ast.literal_eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) method: [Python: make eval safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3513475/13552470)

Of course, it would require you to install the `ast` module, and the string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None.